# Chrome suddenly won't load in Ubuntu 23.10

Tags: apt, google-chrome, deb

When I logged in today Chrome will not load. Clicking on the icon does nothing. I rebooted. I used `sudo apt reinstall google-chrome-stable`. Nothing. I re-downloaded the .deb package from Google and used `sudo apt purge google-chrome-stable` and then reinstalled it from the downloaded package. Nothing seems to work. I changed the name of the computer recently but that's the only change I can think of. Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

Changing the name of the computer somehow broke Chrome. I changed it back and now it works fine. I still need to rename it so I need to figure out how to do that without making Chrome stop working. I am wondering if uninstalling Chrome, then changing the name, then installing Chrome again will work.